# Can someone explain what this eval command looking at AWS credentials is doing?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, gitlab

I am looking at some scripts used in our GitLab pipeline and came across the below line.

```
eval "$(jq -r '@sh "ACCOUNT_NAME=\(.account_name) ENVIRONMENT=\(.environment) AWS_REGION=\(.aws_region) COMPONENT=\(.component) CONTEXT=\(.context) ACCOUNT_NBR=\(.account_nbr)"')"
```

What is the `.account_name, .environment,` etc? I have never heard of AWS storing anything in those.

Why is eval used here?

Comment: `What is the` ask the author. `Why is eval used here?` "Why" something is used, you can only ask the author. How can we know? `what this eval command looking` It's doing the same as anywhere else it would be doing - evaluating the string passed to it as an argument. `What is the .account_name, .environment, etc?` See `jq` documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the use of 'eval' here is simply to set the shell variables ACCOUNT_NAME, ENVIRONMENT, etc. It's doing that by using "raw" output (-r) and using '@sh' to escape those values to be valid in the shell.